# Is right to say that "Stack Overflow runs on top of Stack Exchange"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange

We all know Stack Exchange is somewhat a fork of the Stack Overflow platform. But I just had to ask if it's still just right to say that "Stack Overflow runs on top of Stack Exchange".

Comment: I think you're actually looking for a name for the SO **engine**, and supposed it could be called StackExchange. I at least was hoping it had a name, but it doesn't so far.

Answer (score 9):

Seeing as how they are indeed forks to some degree, I think the correct answer would be "No"

It would be more accurate to say that StackExchange is an offshoot project based off of the success of the original StackOverflow Trilogy of websites.

Comment: I know, right? Stack Overflow runs on top of waffles.

Comment: and powered by pink pony poop.

Answer (score 5):

I would say:

> "Stack Overflow runs on a similar engine to the one powering Stack Exchange."

I suspect neither is a superset of the other - calling attention to the similarity is probably accurate and appropriately fuzzy. Of course, how much detail you can provide depends on who you're talking to.

Answer (score 3):

> Seeing as how they are indeed forks to some degree, I think the correct answer would be "No"
>
> It would be more accurate to say that StackExchange is an offshoot project based off of the success of the original StackOverflow Trilogy of websites.
>
> answered 2 hours ago
> TheTXI♦

---

> I know, right? Stack Overflow runs on top of waffles. – Welbo_g 2 hours ago
> and powered by pink pony poop. – Greg Hewgill 11 mins ago

This reminded me of the true inside of Django
[alt text http://www.tokumine.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/pony-magic_s.jpg](http://www.tokumine.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/pony-magic_s.jpg)

What would the C# mascot be?

Answer (score 1):

I would say:

> StackOverflow and StackExchange use different engines that share a common code base.

Because while much of the code is the same, they have forked some as well.

Answer (score 0):

It would be an awful code duplication infringement if it didn't.